# unable to go to first tab bar from another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbar

Unable to go to first tab bar from another viewcontroller. tabbar is declared in appdelegate.Please help. Is there any other way to do?
I want to go to first tab bar in anyway.

```
- (IBAction)createThread:(id)sender {


BOOL isNetworkAvailable=[[IXNetworkDataManager sharedNetworkDataManager] checkForNetworkConnection];

if(isNetworkAvailable)
{

    NSDate *replyDateInfo = [NSDate date];

    NSString *loginUser=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentUser"];



        UserInfo *info=[[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] retrieveCurrentUserDetailsForUser:loginUser];
        if(info!=nil)
        {

            [[IXNetworkDataManager sharedNetworkDataManager] createThreadWithDetails:self.selectedMessageArray];

   [self manageThreadWithDetails:self.selectedMessageArray];

AppDelegate *sharedDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[sharedDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

//[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];




 }
```

Comment: check if `sharedDelegate` or `tabBarController` equals `nil`

Comment: They are not nil, I have checked them.